# Entity Browser Widget for Video Embed Media Entity

Tags: 8, entities, media

I have a few different Entity Browsers setup for uploading or selecting Media Entities on my Drupal 8.3.x site.

I have Image, Document & Video media bundles setup on the site.

The Image & Document providers include widgets to add to an Entity Browser.

Video bundle is setup via the video_embed module through media_entity module.

I can not find any documentation or method of adding an 'Add New Video' type of widget for Entity Browser – ie. A simple text field in which you paste in the URL of a Vimeo/Youtube video to create an entity for it.

My Video Entity is working fine on the standalone creation form.

I also have a View (Entity browser widget plugin) I'm using for selecting **Existing** videos on the site, and that works fine.

Are there any existing methods for an 'Add Video'

[image: Add Widget Plugin Dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any way to implement an 'Add New Video' widget to an Entity Browser.

There is a solution using Inline Entity Form. https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form

With Inline Entity Form, you can have an entity creation option, or add existing entity option.  You can then use an Entity Browser for selecting existing entities, and leave the adding of new entities up to Inline Entity Form.

It's quite a clean User Interface / User Experience once implemented:

[image: Add Node UI with Inline Entity Form and Entity Browser]

Answer (score 1):

Amended Solution:

At the time of writing the question, for some unknown reason, the 'Entity Form' widget was unavailable from the Add Widget dropdown.

After a fair bit of work on other areas, the 'Entity Form' option is now available.

It's now fairly trivial to add a basic form for creating a single video:

[image: Widget Selector]

Comment: To make available the "Entity form" option in the "Add widget plugin" dropdown you have to enable the "Entity Browser IEF" submodule provided by "Entity browser" module.